# Process subclass property returns wrong value during testing

Tags: python, pytest

I've build a simple MongoDB changestream listener based on a Process subclass to sidestep the GIL. In this class I want to have an auto-restart behaviour if the DB connection gets interrupted. However the Listener should stop if it has been restarted itself 5 times in 5 minutes.

My listener class code:

```py
import sys
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import time

class Listener(Process):

    # Holds the number how many times the listener has restarted itself
    __no_restarts: int = 0
    __last_start_time: float = 0

    def __init__(self, 
            max_restart: int = 5,
            max_restart_minute: int = 5
        ) -> None:

        # Sets the number of maximum restarts before the listener ultimateliy fails
        # max_restart_minute is the window in which the max restarts will be measure. 
        self.max_restart = max_restart
        self.max_restart_sec = max_restart_minute * 60

        # Init the listener through superclass
        super(Listener, self).__init__()

    @property
    def max_restarts_reached(self) -> bool:
        if (self.__no_restarts >= self.max_restart) and ((time.time() - self.__last_start_time) <= self.max_restart_sec):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def run(self):
        
        # Set the time of the last start of the listener. Also add one start to the iterator
        self.__last_start_time = time.time()
        self.__no_restarts += 1

        try:
            ### The Changestream Listening stuff

        # Restarts the listener if we got an error
        except PyMongoError as e:
            
            # Check if we hit the max number of restarts during our 5 minute window
            if self.max_restarts_reached:
                print('Failed')
                return sys.exit(1)

            # Otherwise restart the process
            else:

                # Exponential backoff to sleep depending on the number of restarts
                time.sleep(pow(1, self.__no_restarts))

                return self.run()
```

My testing code for the max_restarts_reached property:

```py
import pytest
import time

import Listener

def test_max_restarts_reached():

    # Init a new mongoDB listener
    mdb_listener = Listener(max_restart = 5, max_restart_minute = 5)
    

    # Sets the last start time. This is normally done in the run() method
    mdb_listener.__last_start_time = time.time()

    # This should be false, since we faked that we just started
    assert mdb_listener.max_restarts_reached == False

    # Set the number of restarts to 10 and check that returns true
    mdb_listener.__no_restarts = 10
    assert mdb_listener.max_restarts_reached == True

    # Expire the restart window. Should then be False again
    mdb_listener.__last_start_time = time.time() - 50
    assert mdb_listener.max_restarts_reached == False
```

In my test I do not start the process itself, but rather emulate the behaviour inside run() by setting the __last_start_time and __no_restarts from the test. The first assertion works well.

On this assert the property returns False although the If condition should be True:

```py
mdb_listener.__no_restarts = 10
assert mdb_listener.max_restarts_reached == True
```

When I debug my test, and eval the If condition it evals to *True*.
[Debugger_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIC1S.png)

I also tried to convert the property to a function, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I'm changing the values of __last_start_time and __no_restarts inside my test. Although these are private variables, the VS Code Debugger showed the new values so I assumed the values acutally changed.

However when printed, these values remained at their default (0). I still don't know why the debugger produced different result though.

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import time

class Listener(Process):

    # Holds the number how many times the listener has restarted itself
    no_restarts: int = 0
    last_start_time: float = 0

    def __init__(self, 
            max_restart: int = 5,
            max_restart_minute: int = 5
        ) -> None:

        # Sets the number of maximum restarts before the listener ultimateliy fails
        # max_restart_minute is the window in which the max restarts will be measure. 
        self.max_restart = max_restart
        self.max_restart_sec = max_restart_minute * 60

        # Init the listener as superclass
        super(Listener, self).__init__()

    @property
    def max_restarts_reached(self) -> bool:
        if (self.no_restarts >= self.max_restart) and ((time.time() - self.last_start_time) <= self.max_restart_sec):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def run(self):
        
        # Set the time of the last start of the listener. Also add one start to the iterator
        self.last_start_time = time.time()
        self.no_restarts += 1

        try:
            ### The Changestream Listening stuff

        # Restarts the listener if we got an error
        except PyMongoError as e:
            
            # Check if we hit the max number of restarts during our 5 minute window
            if self.max_restarts_reached:
                print('Failed')
                return sys.exit(1)

            # Otherwise restart the process
            else:

                # Exponential backoff to sleep depending on the number of restarts
                time.sleep(pow(1, self.no_restarts))

                return self.run()
```